# Visual Studio, Make textbox choose between Different values

Tags: visual-studio

I'm pretty new to Visual Studio (2005). I have a textbox which must display 2 different strings based on another textbox field.

```
Example
Textbox 1 = "Education"
Textbox 2 Needs to be "Date"
but if
Textbox 1 = "Language"
Textbox 2 needs to be "Knowledge"
```

I have trying some Iif functions, but I can't get it right. How can I fix this?

Comment: "Visual Studio" doesn't have any textboxes. At least not any that you can change. What programming language are you using? What GUI framework are you using? How are you setting the values of these textboxes? What code do you have now?

Answer (score -1):

in the change event of the OTHER textbox you can change the text. or use a business layer and databinding.

Comment: What change event? "A business layer and databinding" tells me absolutely nothing. This answer is not helpful.

Comment: the change event of the textbox. you asked for "visual studio", and your sample source is a little more visual basic then c#, but anyway: THERE ARE EVENTS! And not helpful: Nobody here will do your homework. A little bit of research has to be done by yourself. I gave you a correct hint.

Comment: (Hint: I'm not the person who asked the question.)